# If $(X,Y)$, $(X',Y')$ are iid. real-valued RV, is $\mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y) = \mathbb{E}(X' \cdot Y')$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I need a bit of help with the statement in the title that I have encountered in a proof of Hoeffding's covariance equality in my statistics course.

We begin by assuming that we can generate an independent copy of $(X,Y)$, let's call it $(X',Y')$. An independent copy is coinciding in distribution by definition, so $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X' \leq x, Y \leq y) = F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$. That is exactly the definition of iid random variables, if I am not mistaken.

The step where I am stuck at is why $2\mathbb{E}(XY) - 2\mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X-X')(Y-Y')$. I have already shown that any pair of mixed variables is independent of each other, so $\mathbb{E}(XY')= \mathbb{E}(X'Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)$ by noticing $\mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}_{X'}$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y = \mathbb{P}_{Y'}$ (using continuity of measures). The only thing missing now is the questioned equality in the title. I don't know if it is true, but multiplying out the right side strongly suggests equality.

I have thought about rewriting $\mathbb{P}(XY \leq x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as a countable union in a way, so that variables can be pulled apart as seperate conditions and using the definition of the pair $(X',Y')$, but as of now I am still in the dark on how to approach this.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The step where I am stuck at is why $2\mathbb{E}(XY) - 2\mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X-X')(Y-Y')$.

$$\begin{align}E[(X-X')(Y-Y')]
&=E[XY -XY' - X'Y + X'Y']\\[2mm]
&=E[XY] -E[XY'] - E[X'Y] + E[X'Y']\\[2mm]
&=E[XY] -E[X]\,E[Y'] - E[X']\,E[Y] + E[X'Y']\\[2mm]
&=E[XY] -E[X]\,E[Y] - E[X]\,E[Y] + E[XY]\\[2mm]
&=2\,E[XY]-2\,E[X]E[Y]\end{align}$$

where we have used the following two facts:

1. If $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$ are **independent**, then $E[XY']=E[X]\,E[Y']$ and $E[X'Y]=E[X']\,E[Y].$
2. If $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$ are **identically distributed** with c.d.f. $F$, then for any integrable function $f$,
   $$E[f(X,Y)]=\int f(x,y)\,dF(x,y)=E[f(X',Y')].$$ (Therefore, $E[X]=E[X'],\ \ E[Y]=E[Y'],\ $ and $E[XY]=E[X'Y'].$)

Comment: Well, the third to second line from the bottom is essentially my question again. So I could equivalently state it as: Why is $\mathbb{E}[(X'-\mathbb{E}X')(Y'-\mathbb{E}Y')] = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}X)(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)]$? I would like to have a way to prove it by calculation, if that is possible in any way. I have a solid background in probability theory, so overpowered tools are also welcome.

Comment: $Ef(X,Y)=\int f(x,y)\,dF(x,y)=Ef(X',Y')$ because $F'=F$; i.e. $(X',Y')$ and $(X,Y)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems ignorant, but how does this help us with the product of the two random variables $XY$ and $X'Y'$? How do we go from the joint random variables to their product and still preserve their expectation?

Comment: Just let $f(X,Y)=(X-\mathbb{E}X)(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay, I thought about it for a while and I think my problem is the equality $\mathbb{E}f(X,Y) = \int f(x,y) \, dF(x,y)$ you stated. I tried proving it by way of transformation theorems and previously proven statements, but I get lost on how to get a transformation from $(x,y)$ to $(X,Y)$. If it does not take too much work, could you go through the steps?

Comment: Wait, I got it. I just swapped the position of the functions for the transformation in my head. Seems good. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The following is true (and holds for any $X, Y$ for which $XY$ is integrable):
$$E(XY) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xy\,dP_{(X, Y)}(x, y).$$
The assumption that $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ are identically distributed means $P_{(X, Y)} = P_{(X', Y')}$ (this is an equality of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^2$). So
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xy\,dP_{(X, Y)}(x, y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xy\,dP_{(X', Y')}(x, y) = E(X'Y').$$
Note that no independence assumption was necessary.

Comment: Yes, I was able to condense the argument from r.e.s. to just about what you have written there. If I am not mistaken, this result applies to *any* family of such independent vectors, which means one can always swap the variables with their counterparts. Neat!

Comment: @TheOutZ Well, above I did not use independence at all. You can summarize the result as saying that if $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued random variables that are identically distributed, then $E(X) = E(Y)$. The answer I wrote above can be seen as a special case of this result since $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ being identically distributed implies $XY = f(X, Y)$ and $X'Y' = f(X', Y')$ are identically distributed.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that shortly after sending my comment. Apologies! Thanks anyway.